# how do I position two objects that are floated right?

Tags: html, css

I have two Divs that are floated right, but I would like one to come before the other. right now the #logout div is to the left of the #theme div. how do I get them to both float right but switch positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is golden rule in programming and any field where it is related with developement.

### KISS: Keep it short and simple

Its a very simple logic, why are you thinking complex on such simple problem?

#### JUST Switch your Markup

Answer (score 4):

The quickest answer is to switch the order in which the `div` tags appear in the HTML.  If that's not an option, then you might have to drop the `float` and do some manual positioning using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If both the elements were display:inline, you could use text-align:right on the parent to move both elements to the right. It depends on what you are trying to do, but this may solve your problem.